# std::lock_guard (mutex) produces deadlock

Tags: mutex, deadlock

First: Thanks for reading this question and tryin' to help me out. I'm new to the whole threading topic and I'm facing a serious mutex deadlock bug right now.

Short introduction:

I wrote a game engine a few months ago, which works perfectly and is being used in games already. This engine is based on SDL2. I wanted to improve my code by making it thread safe, which would be very useful to increase performance or to play around with some other theoretical concepts.

The problem:

The game uses internal game stages to display different states of a game, like displaying the menu, or displaying other parts of the game. When entering the "Asteroid Game"-stage I recieve an exception, which is thrown by the std::lock_guard constructor call.

The problem in detail:

When entering the "Asteroid Game"-stage a modelGetDirection() function is being called to recieve a direction vector of a model. This function uses a lock_guard to make this function being thread safe. When debugging this code section this is where the exception is thrown. The program would enter this lock_guard constructor and would throw an exception. The odd thing is, that this function is NEVER being called before. This is the first time this function is being called and every test run would crash right here!

this is where the debugger would stop in threadx:

```
inline int _Mtx_lockX(_Mtx_t _Mtx)
{   // throw exception on failure
return (_Check_C_return(_Mtx_lock(_Mtx)));
}
```

And here are the actual code snippets which I think are important:

mutex struct:

```
struct LEMutexModel
{
  // of course there are more mutexes inside here
  mutex modelGetDirection;
};
```

engine class:

```
typedef class LEMoon
{
  private:

    LEMutexModel mtxModel;

    // other mutexes, attributes, methods and so on

  public:

    glm::vec2 modelGetDirection(uint32_t, uint32_t);

    // other methods
} *LEMoonInstance;
```

modelGetDirection() (engine)function definition:

```
glm::vec2 LEMoon::modelGetDirection(uint32_t id, uint32_t idDirection)
{
  lock_guard<mutex> lockA(this->mtxModel.modelGetDirection);
  glm::vec2 direction = {0.0f, 0.0f};
  LEModel * pElem = this->modelGet(id);

  if(pElem == nullptr)
    {pElem = this->modelGetFromBuffer(id);}

  if(pElem != nullptr)
    {direction = pElem->pModel->mdlGetDirection(idDirection);}
  else
  {
    #ifdef LE_DEBUG
      char * pErrorString = new char[256 + 1];
      sprintf(pErrorString, "LEMoon::modelGetDirection(%u)\n\n", id);
      this->printErrorDialog(LE_MDL_NOEXIST, pErrorString);
      delete [] pErrorString;
    #endif
  }

  return direction;
}
```

this is the game function that uses the modelGetDirection method! This function would control a space ship:

```
void Game::level1ControlShip(void * pointer, bool controlAble)
{
  Parameter param = (Parameter) pointer;
  static glm::vec2 currentSpeedLeft = {0.0f, 0.0f};
  glm::vec2 speedLeft = param->engine->modelGetDirection(MODEL_VERA, LEFT);
  static const double INCREASE_SPEED_LEFT = (1.0f / VERA_INCREASE_LEFT) * speedLeft.x * (-1.0f);
// ... more code, I think that's not important
}
```

So as mentioned before: When entering the level1ControlShip() function, the programm will enter the modelGetDirection() function. When entering the modelGetDirection() function an exception will be thrown when tryin' to call:

```
lock_guard<mutex> lockA(this->mtxModel.modelGetDirection);
```

And as mentioned, this is the first call of this function in the whole application run!

So why is that? I appreciate any help here! The whole engine (not the game) is an open source project and can be found on gitHub in case I forgot some important code snippets (sorry! in that case):

[GitHub: Lynar Moon Engine](https://github.com/Lynarstudios/LEMoon/)

Thanks for your help!

Greetings,
Patrick

Comment: What exception?

Comment: Title says "deadlock", but you don't mention deadlock when describing the problem, instead you talking about exception. So what exception are we talking about? Also you should attach you stack trace so people could see what exactly was happening.